# C Arbitrary length string

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have a doubt how the length for an array is allocated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "s";
    long unsigned a = strlen(str);
    scanf("%s", str);
    printf("%s\n%lu\n", str, a);
    return 0;
}
```

In the above program, I assign the string `"s"` to a `char` array.
I thought the length of `str[]` is 1. so we cannot store more than the length of the array. But it behaves differently. If I reading a string using `scanf` it is stored in `str[]` without any error. What was the length of the array `str`?

Sample I/O :

```
Hello

Hello 1
```

Comment: It's undefined behavior and can cause hard tracked bugs, so don't go out of bounds.

Comment: There might not be an error today, but there will be one tomorrow. If you break the speed limit, you don't necessarily cause an accident. Only if you hit something. Here, your out-of-bounds string hasn't hit anything.

Comment: Crashing is the second best case behavior if you have Undefined Behavior. Best case would be a compiler error/warning, but in many situations C compilers don't provide any diagnostics for such things. Worse things that may happen if you write beyond the end of a buffer: arbitrary code execution, i.e. a bad security vulnerability in your code, compromised data integrity, data confidentiality,...

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s", str);`  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.   Note: the `scanf()` family of functions returns the number of successful `input format conversion` specifiers (or EOF)   In the current scenario, any returned value other than 1 indicates and error occurred.   2) (note the length of the buffer `str[]` is 2) When using the specifier: `%s` and/or `%[...]` always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those specifiers always append a NUL bytet.  (cont)

Comment: (cont) this also avoids any possibility of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `str` is an array of `char` initialized with `"s"`, that is, it has size `2` and length `1`. The size is one more than the length because a NUL string terminator character (`\0`) is added at the end.

Your `str` array can hold *at most* two `char`. Trying to write more will cause your program to access memory past the end of the array, which is undefined behavior.

What actually happens though, is that since the `str` array is stored somewhere in memory (on the stack), and that memory region is far larger than 2 bytes, you are actually able to write past the end without causing a crash. This does ***not*** mean that you should. It's still undefined behavior.

Since your array has size `2`, it can only hold a string of length `1`, plus its terminator. To use `scanf()` and correctly avoid writing past the end of the array, you can use the field width specifier: a numeric value after the `%` and before the `s`, like this:

```
scanf("%1s", str);
```

Answer (score 4):

When an array is declared without specifying its size when the size is determined by the used initializers.

In this declaration of an array

```
char str[] = "s";
```

there is used a string literal as an initializer. A string literal is a sequence of characters terminated by an included zero-terminating character. That is the string literal `"s"` has two characters `{ 's', '\0' }`.

Its characters are used to initialize sequentially elements of the array `str`.

So if you will write

```
printf( "sizeof( str ) = %zu\n", sizeof( str ) );
```

then the output will be `2`. The length of a string is determinate as a number of characters before the terminating zero character. So if you will write

```
#include <string.h>
//...
printf( "strlen( str ) = %zu\n", strlen( str ) );
```

then the output will be `1`.

If you will try to write data outside an array then you will get undefined behavior because a memory that does not belong to the array will be overwritten. In some cases you can get the expected result. In other cases the program can finish abnormally. That is the behavior of the program is undefined.

Answer (score 4):

The array `str` has size 2: 1 byte for the character 's' and one for the terminating null byte.  What you're doing is writing past the end of the array.  Doing so invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

When your code has undefined behavior, it could crash, it could output strange results, or it could (as in this case) appear to work properly.  Also, making a seemingly unrelated change such as a `printf` call for debugging or an unused local variable can change how undefined behavior manifests itself.